# Montor an android app remote webservice calling information

Tags: android, web-services, process, monitoring

I would like to find and monitor all of the web services which are called by an android app on my phone. Is there any android tools for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this app, I will share few more tools

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture

Comment: Thanks, may you please share the tools?

Comment: do you need tool for debugging ?